# Problem with getElementsByTagName in IE 8

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I have problem this script dont working in IE 8 in Firefox is everything OK.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
 lip{   position:absolute;     }
</style>
<body>
<ul><lip>3<input type = "checkbox" name = "LH3" id ='lhpz12' value="ANO"></lip></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listElements = document.getElementsByTagName("lip");
var element = listElements[0];
    element.style.fontSize = "24px";
    element.style.color = "green";
    element.style.left = "100px";
    element.style.top = "100px";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's a "lip" element? Should that be "li"? Please describe the actual problem behaviour that you get in IE8, e.g., "Nothing happens" or "Error xyz is displayed" or...

Answer (score 4):

LIP isnt a valid tag, use something like a span or div.

Comment: Indeed. Internet Explorer isn't very good at handling things that are not HTML but claim to be (and "not HTML" includes most new things introduced in HTML 5 drafts).

Comment: Your right and of course, it's also better to use jQuery (http://jqueryui.com/) for this kind of trouble.

Comment: `<span>` and `<div>` elements are not valid inside `<ul>` elements. You might want to suggest using `<li>` instead.

Comment: Quentin: IE 9 has support for those and the code snippet works for me there.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, those tags aren't until you create one in JavaScript. You should use a `span` here.

Comment: `ul` may only contain `li` elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2